# Saving or updating to databse

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

What would be the best way to refactor following method?

```
public void AddOrUpdateDesign(DesignInformation designInformation,
                            CommonTransformerProperties commonTransformerProperties,
                            SecondaryWindings secondaryWindings,
                            CapacitorVoltageDivider capacitorVoltageDivider,
                            IntermediateVoltageTransformer intermediateVoltageTransformer,
                            SpecialDesignInformation specialDesignInformation,
                            TransformerLimits transformerLimits)
    {


        using (var context = new DesignContext())
        {
            Design design;
            if (!DesignExist(context, designInformation.DesignID))
            {

                context.DesignInformation.Add(designInformation);
                context.CommonTransformerPropeteries.Add(commonTransformerProperties);
                context.SecondaryWindings.Add(secondaryWindings);
                context.CapacitorVoltageDivider.Add(capacitorVoltageDivider);
                context.IntermediateVoltageTransformer.Add(intermediateVoltageTransformer);
                context.SpecialDesignInformation.Add(specialDesignInformation);
                context.TransformerLimits.Add(transformerLimits);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
            else
            context.Dispose();
            {
                if (designInformation.DataBaseID ==0)
                {
                     using (var newcontext = new DesignContext()) 
                {
                    design = GetDesingByNameFromDatabase(newcontext, designInformation.DesignID, designInformation.Technology);

                    var existingSecondaryWindings = newcontext.SecondaryWindings.Include("WindingsCollection").First(x => x.DataBaseID == design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID);

                    var existingWindingsCollection = existingSecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.ToList<SecondaryWinding>();

                    var updateWindings = secondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.ToList<SecondaryWinding>();

                    var addWindings = updateWindings.Except(existingWindingsCollection, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);

                    var delteWindings = existingWindingsCollection.Except(updateWindings, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);

                    var modifyWindings = updateWindings.Except(addWindings, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);

                    foreach (var item in addWindings)
                    {
                        design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.Add(item);
                    }

                    design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCount = secondaryWindings.WindingsCount;

                    delteWindings.ToList<SecondaryWinding>().ForEach(wind => newcontext.Entry(wind).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);

                    foreach (var winding in modifyWindings)
                    {
                        var existingWindings = design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.First(x => x.SecondaryWindingId == winding.SecondaryWindingId);
                        if (existingWindings != null)
                        {
                            var windingEntry = newcontext.Entry(existingWindings);
                            windingEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(winding);

                        }
                    }

                    ///special design

                    var existingSpecialDesignWire = newcontext.SpecialDesignInformation.Include("SecondaryWindingWireDimensions").First(x => x.DataBaseID == design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID);

                    var existingWireCollection = existingSpecialDesignWire.SecondaryWindingWireDimensions.ToList<SpecialDesignSecondaryWire>();

                    var updateWires = specialDesignInformation.SecondaryWindingWireDimensions.ToList<SpecialDesignSecondaryWire>();

                    var addWire = updateWires.Except(existingWireCollection, wind => wind.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID);

                    var deleteWire = existingWireCollection.Except(updateWires, wind => wind.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID);

                    var modifyWires = updateWires.Except(addWire, wind => wind.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID);

                    foreach (var item in addWire)
                    {
                        design.SpecialDesignInformation.SecondaryWindingWireDimensions.Add(item);
                    }

                    deleteWire.ToList<SpecialDesignSecondaryWire>().ForEach(wire => newcontext.Entry(wire).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);

                    foreach (var wire in modifyWires)
                    {
                        var existingWires = existingWireCollection.Find(x => x.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID == wire.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID);
                        if (existingWires != null)
                        {
                            var wireEntry = newcontext.Entry(existingWires);
                            wireEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(wire);
                        }
                    }

                    newcontext.SaveChanges();
                }
                     int dbId = design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID;

                     design.DesignInformation = designInformation;
                     design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID = dbId;

                     design.CommonTransformerProperties = commonTransformerProperties;
                     design.CommonTransformerProperties.DataBaseID = dbId;

                     design.SecondaryWindings = secondaryWindings;
                     design.SecondaryWindings.DataBaseID = dbId;

                     design.CapacitorVoltageDivider = capacitorVoltageDivider;
                     design.CapacitorVoltageDivider.DataBaseID = dbId;

                     design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer = intermediateVoltageTransformer;
                     design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer.DataBaseID = dbId;

                     design.SpecialDesignInformation = specialDesignInformation;
                     design.SpecialDesignInformation.DataBaseID = dbId;

                     using(var newcontext = new DesignContext())
                     {
                         newcontext.Entry(design.CommonTransformerProperties).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                         newcontext.Entry(design.SecondaryWindings).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                         newcontext.Entry(design.CapacitorVoltageDivider).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                         newcontext.Entry(design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                         newcontext.Entry(design.SpecialDesignInformation).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                         newcontext.Entry(design.DesignInformation).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                         newcontext.SaveChanges();
                         return;
                     }
                }

                }

                context.Dispose();
                using (var newcontext = new DesignContext()) 
                {
                    design = GetDesingByNameFromDatabase(newcontext, designInformation.DesignID, designInformation.Technology);

                    var existingSecondaryWindings = newcontext.SecondaryWindings.Include("WindingsCollection").First(x => x.DataBaseID == designInformation.DataBaseID);

                    var existingWindingsCollection = existingSecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.ToList<SecondaryWinding>();

                    var updateWindings = secondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.ToList<SecondaryWinding>();

                    var addWindings = updateWindings.Except(existingWindingsCollection, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);

                    var delteWindings = existingWindingsCollection.Except(updateWindings, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);

                    var modifyWindings = updateWindings.Except(addWindings, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);

                    foreach (var item in addWindings)
                    {
                        design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.Add(item);
                    }

                    design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCount = secondaryWindings.WindingsCount;

                    delteWindings.ToList<SecondaryWinding>().ForEach(wind => newcontext.Entry(wind).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);

                    foreach (var winding in modifyWindings)
                    {
                        var existingWindings = design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.First(x => x.SecondaryWindingId == winding.SecondaryWindingId);
                        if (existingWindings != null)
                        {
                            var windingEntry = newcontext.Entry(existingWindings);
                            windingEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(winding);

                        }
                    }

                    ///special design

                    var existingSpecialDesignWire = newcontext.SpecialDesignInformation.Include("SecondaryWindingWireDimensions").First(x => x.DataBaseID == designInformation.DataBaseID);

                    var existingWireCollection = existingSpecialDesignWire.SecondaryWindingWireDimensions.ToList<SpecialDesignSecondaryWire>();

                    var updateWires = specialDesignInformation.SecondaryWindingWireDimensions.ToList<SpecialDesignSecondaryWire>();

                    var addWire = updateWires.Except(existingWireCollection, wind => wind.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID);

                    var deleteWire = existingWireCollection.Except(updateWires, wind => wind.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID);

                    var modifyWires = updateWires.Except(addWire, wind => wind.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID);

                    foreach (var item in addWire)
                    {
                        design.SpecialDesignInformation.SecondaryWindingWireDimensions.Add(item);
                    }

                    deleteWire.ToList<SpecialDesignSecondaryWire>().ForEach(wire => newcontext.Entry(wire).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);

                    foreach (var wire in modifyWires)
                    {
                        var existingWires = existingWireCollection.Find(x => x.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID == wire.SpecialDesignSecondaryWireID);
                        if (existingWires != null)
                        {
                            var wireEntry = newcontext.Entry(existingWires);
                            wireEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(wire);
                        }
                    }

                    newcontext.SaveChanges();
                }

                design.DesignInformation = designInformation;
                design.CommonTransformerProperties = commonTransformerProperties;
                design.SecondaryWindings = secondaryWindings;
                design.CapacitorVoltageDivider = capacitorVoltageDivider;
                design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer = intermediateVoltageTransformer;
                design.SpecialDesignInformation = specialDesignInformation;

                using (var newcontext = new DesignContext())
                {
                    newcontext.Entry(design.DesignInformation).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    newcontext.Entry(design.CommonTransformerProperties).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    newcontext.Entry(design.SecondaryWindings).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    newcontext.Entry(design.CapacitorVoltageDivider).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    newcontext.Entry(design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    newcontext.Entry(design.SpecialDesignInformation).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    newcontext.SaveChanges();
                }
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too much copy-paste, use private methods for code allocation. For example

```
private void UpdateSecondaryWindings(Design design, DesignContext newcontext, DesignInformation designInformation) {
    var existingSecondaryWindings = newcontext.SecondaryWindings.Include("WindingsCollection").First(x => x.DataBaseID == design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID);
    var existingWindingsCollection = existingSecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.ToList<SecondaryWinding>();
    var updateWindings = secondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.ToList<SecondaryWinding>();
    var addWindings = updateWindings.Except(existingWindingsCollection, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);
    var delteWindings = existingWindingsCollection.Except(updateWindings, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);
    var modifyWindings = updateWindings.Except(addWindings, wind => wind.SecondaryWindingId);

    foreach (var item in addWindings)
    {
        design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.Add(item);
    }

    design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCount = secondaryWindings.WindingsCount;

    delteWindings.ToList<SecondaryWinding>().ForEach(wind => newcontext.Entry(wind).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);

    foreach (var winding in modifyWindings)
    {
        var existingWindings = design.SecondaryWindings.WindingsCollection.First(x => x.SecondaryWindingId == winding.SecondaryWindingId);
        if (existingWindings != null)
        {
            var windingEntry = newcontext.Entry(existingWindings);
            windingEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(winding);
        }
    }
}
```

When you have function or procedure with 4 or more parameters you can create class and pass instance. Example, you can create `DesignProperties` class

```
internal class DesignProperties {
DesignInformation DesignInformation {get;set;}
CommonTransformerProperties CommonTransformerProperties {get;set;}
SecondaryWindings SecondaryWindings {get;set;}
CapacitorVoltageDivider CapacitorVoltageDivider {get;set;}
IntermediateVoltageTransformer IntermediateVoltageTransformer {get;set;}
SpecialDesignInformation SpecialDesignInformation  {get;set;}
TransformerLimits TransformerLimits {get;set;}
}
```

And then

```
public void AddOrUpdateDesign(DesignProperties properties){
    ...
}
```

Your `DesignContext` also can have method Add with param `DesignProperties` and calls like this

```
context.Add(designProperties)
```

and your `Design` class can exist method Update

```
public class Design{
    ...
    public void Update(DesignProperties properties){

    }
}
```

If you want to update it with DataBaseID add procedure with bool IsDbIdUpdate

```
public void Update(DesignProperties props, int dbId)
```

and `SaveChanges()` should calls inside this method.

Next one

```
    else
    context.Dispose();
    {
```

I dont understand why you put brackets after dispose method, because code inside always work, also `!DesignExist(context, designInformation.DesignID)` return true. You can remove this brackets.

Add to `DesignContext` function like `SetState()` and

```
newContext.SetState(design, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified);
```

After my edit code should be looks like this

```
public void AddOrUpdateDesign(DesignProperties designProperties)
    {
        Design design;

        using (var context = new DesignContext())
        {
            if (!DesignExist(context, designInformation.DesignID))
                context.Add(designProperties)
        }

        using (var context = new DesignContext()) 
        {
            design = GetDesingByNameFromDatabase(context, designInformation.DesignID, designInformation.Technology);

            UpdateSecondaryWindings(design, context, designInformation);
            UpdateWires(design, context, designInformation);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (designInformation.DataBaseID == 0)
        {
            int dbId = design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID;
            design.Update(designProperties, dbId);
        }
        else
        {
            design.Update(designProperties);
        }

        using(var context = new DesignContext())
        {
            context.SetState(design, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And some private methods )

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.

Comment: I would move `Design design;` down, after the first `using`. I think it's better to declare variables as close to their usage as possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Potential bug / unexpected behaviour**

Here

> ```
> public void AddOrUpdateDesign(DesignInformation designInformation,
>                             CommonTransformerProperties commonTransformerProperties,
>                             SecondaryWindings secondaryWindings,
>                             CapacitorVoltageDivider capacitorVoltageDivider,
>                             IntermediateVoltageTransformer intermediateVoltageTransformer,
>                             SpecialDesignInformation specialDesignInformation,
>                             TransformerLimits transformerLimits)
>     {
>
>
>         using (var context = new DesignContext())
>         {
>             Design design;
>             if (!DesignExist(context, designInformation.DesignID))
>             {
>
>                 context.DesignInformation.Add(designInformation);
>                 context.CommonTransformerPropeteries.Add(commonTransformerProperties);
>                 context.SecondaryWindings.Add(secondaryWindings);
>                 context.CapacitorVoltageDivider.Add(capacitorVoltageDivider);
>                 context.IntermediateVoltageTransformer.Add(intermediateVoltageTransformer);
>                 context.SpecialDesignInformation.Add(specialDesignInformation);
>                 context.TransformerLimits.Add(transformerLimits);
>                 context.SaveChanges();
>
>             }
>             else
>             context.Dispose();
>             {
>                 if (designInformation.DataBaseID ==0)
>                 {
>                      using (var newcontext = new DesignContext()) 
>                 {
> ```

I don't know if you noticed this and if it had been what you want to do, but the code after

> ```
> else
> context.Dispose();
> ```

will be executed no matter what `DesignExists()` will return.